# How can I make a grid-like data structure in python?

Tags: python

What i need to make is

```
          Col 0   Col 1   Col 2 
Row 0       1       0       1 
Row 1       1       1       1 
Row 2       1       1       1
```

The numbers are totally random but I'm totally stuck on how to make the board. The problem is I need to be able to add the numbers up in columns and rows afterwards. Do i have to make it into a list first and them space them out or keep it how it is and space it out with \t.

All i have is a random number generator. I'm not sure what to do next.

```
def generate_random_number(size):
  number = ""
  for i in range(size):
    digits = random.randint(0, 1)
    numbers = number + str(digits)
  return numbers
```

Comment: It is hard to determine what you're asking. I don't think you "have" the random number generator either. As posted that will say: undefined variable digit.

Comment: your `generate_random_number` function is not only missing a local variable (`digit`) but also overwrites the `numbers` variable each time the loop executes, which is certainly not what you want...

Answer (score 2):

My advice would be: choose the data structure so that it's easy to process the data in a reasonable manner. Then you can decide how to visualize the data, but it shouldn't affect the choice of data structure.

In this case it's probably reasonable to store the board as a list of lists (or tuple of tuples) of integers.

Then you can write, for example:

```
def row_sum(table, i):
    return sum(table[i])

def col_sum(table, i):
    return sum(row[i] for row in table)

def print_table(table):
    print ' '*colsize + '\t' + '\t'.join('Col {}'.format(i) for i, _ in enumerate(t))
    for i, row in enumerate(t):
        print 'Row {}'.format(i).ljust(colsize), '\t'.join(str(v).rjust(colsize) for v in row)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend create a list of lists. Where it is essentially a list of rows and then each row has a bunch of cells. The code below will fill it with random values of 0 or 1. There is also code showing you how to sum the row and column values.

**code**

```
import random, pprint

def random_row(size):
    return [random.randrange(2) for i in range(size)] 

data = [random_row(3) for i in range(3)]
pprint.pprint(data, width=20)
print 'row 1 sum:', sum(data[0])
print 'column 1 sum:', sum(row[0] for row in data)
```

**output**

```
[[1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 0]]
row 1 sum: 1
column 1 sum: 2
```

Comment: can the code be changed so that the output doesn't have square brackets and comma's?

Comment: definitely look at Lev Levitsky he uses the same data structure and is printing in a way that you can fully control.

Answer (score 0):

Would it help to see this code example?

```
x = []
for row in range(10):
    x.append([])

for row in x:
   for col in range(10):
       row.append(0)
```

This creates a 10x10 grid of zeros using tuples. Really, it's a tuple containing ten tuples, each containing ten numbers.

Helpful tip, type this:

```
print(x)
```

Then type this:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(x)
```

You'll see the difference. pprint stands for "pretty print". :)

Comment: can the code be changed so that the output doesn't have square brackets and comma's?

Comment: Not really. If you print out a data structure in python, it's going to have that stuff. If you want to print something out looking exactly like what you showed in your question, you're going to have to do it by hand, with print() statements. In that case all I can say is that if you write print(x, end=""), it will not add a newline afterwards. In python 2.x just add a comma after the print statement, i.e. print x,

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like a two-dimensional "array". In python you can use a list of lists to create the structure you have described.

```
#first a list of lists

grid=[[],[],[]]

#you can use it like this

#       |  Col 0        | Col 1        | Col 2
#---------------------------------------------------
# Row 0 |  grid[0][0]=1 | grid[0][1]=0 | grid[0][2]=1
# Row 1 |  grid[1][0]=1 | grid[1][1]=1 | grid[1][2]=1
# Row 2 |  grid[2][0]=1 | grid[2][1]=1 | grid[2][2]=1
```

Adding up the numbers in a row or column is as easy as:

```
def sum_row(row):
  return grid[row][0]+grid[row][1]+grid[row][2]

def sum_column(column):
  return grid[0][column]+grid[1][column]+grid[2][column]
```

Moreover, I don't understand what you're doing with your randomNumber function. It seems like you want to return a string version of the random number but that would result in problems when you try to add up the entries of a column or row. Nevertheless, if you indeed try to get a string of a number, I would write it like this:

```
  def generate_random_number(size):
    number=""
    for i in range(size):
      digit = random.randint(0, 1)
      number = number + str(digit)
    return number
```

Comment: thanks for the help fixing my coding :)